# ISO: Screen Recorder that pauses recording when computer is idle?

Tags: video, screen-recording, display, video-recording

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a screen recorder that stops recording, or pauses recording, when there is no movement onscreen for some defined amount of time, and starts recording as soon as movement is detected. Does anything like that exist?